# How to use VS Code for Jetpack Compose

Tags: kotlin, visual-studio-code, android-jetpack-compose, vscode-extensions

I installed the Kotlin plugin from Mathias Frohlich. But all imports and class references have errors. Honestly, I did expect this because Jetbrains have mentioned that developers have to use Android Studio Arctic Fox to develop using Jetpack Compose.

Is there anyway to make Jetpack Compose compatible with VS Code? May be an unpopular extension? **The thing that I noticed was that VS Code was not able to detect `android` and `androidx` imports**. So if there is a way to solve this first, even if it is hacky, that might be a great start

Comment: Why don't you want to use Android Studio?

Comment: @Johann The support for Compose is great, but it is a bit slower than VSCode and more importantly heavy (To be fair, Visual Studio Community and XCode is also heavy). I used Android Studio when I started Flutter, but now I am using VS Code for my work and personal projects and difference is huge for me personally.

Comment: When was the last time you used Android Studio? In the past, it use to be slow. But that really isn't the case anymore. I use both VSC and Android Studio but can't even imagine building any professional app using anything but Android Studio.

Comment: @Johann I am using it right now as I can't use VSCode for Compose. I don't hate it. But the experience is not as streamlined and smooth as in VSCode. I made the switch to VSCode because of the same reason. My productivity increased and the overall experience was marginally different.
Full fledged IDEs like Android Studio and Visual Studio Community does a lot of things for you, but still end up being slower. As they say, there are no zero cost abstractions. And since such IDEs have a lot to keep track of, they are fundamentally heavier for development.

Comment: @Johann I am using VSCode for my work and my own projects. Considering my own projects as unprofessional, my work still counts as a professional app. I am not religious about IDEs, just want to have a fast, smooth and streamlined experience. If any other IDE can deliver that to me, I will use that over VSCode anytime

Comment: @AldrinMathew have you found any solution yet? I am currently using vscode for flutter but recently started using jetpack compose to build native apps as well. I was searching for a solution and found this post.

Comment: @FahimHoque Not yet, I prefer VS Code because it genuinely makes the workflow easier and is flexible. Tooling for a framework like Compose is very important, but if the development team does not focus on that, what can we do - just wait for some hacks to come by. From my experience, most Android developers are stuck with Android Studio, which is sad because it actually makes your development slower, like most GUI-heavy IDEs do.

Comment: I would point out more logics in favor of VS code but that would probably go against the rules of stack, but yes between android studio and vscode I would choose code 10 out of 10 times